# Failed to connect to Neo4j db via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j

When I try to connect to Neo4j db by client.Connect(); from Neo4jClient it throws 404:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.
```

The response status was: `404 Not Found`

This error occurs either in my projects or demo projects on Neo4jClient.
Config:
url: http://localhost:7474/db/data"

- login: neo4j" (by default)
- password: "1234" (default "neo4j" was changed to "1234"

Tried with Neo4j Desktop and Neo4j Community Edititon and it happens in both cases. (Service is running, using 7474 port).

With docs I don't see why this problem arises. Any ideas why this may haplen and what do I miss?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the db successfully by some other means? Or not at all?

Comment: Like what? 
I can access it directly via Neo4j Desktop Browser or browser itself when service is running.

Comment: Ok, it's good you can access it via Neo4j Desktop Browser. Can you add the code where you initialize `client`?

Comment: What do you see when you try curl to access it? `curl -i --user neo4j:1234 http://localhost:7474/db/data/`

Comment: My code is now based on official examples. Which are working with this behaviour too (404 Response). (example: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-dotnet-neo4jclient)

Comment: Can you try including a trailing slash in the URL? (in your C# code) `http://localhost:7474/db/data/`

Comment: about curl: `Invoke-WebRequest : Не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент "http://localhost:7474/db/data/".
строка:1 знак:1
+ curl -i --user neo4j:1234 http://localhost:7474/db/data/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

Russian->Eng translation: "Wasn't able to find positioning parameter, which takes  argument ..."

Comment: Trailing slash didn't help

Comment: I'd try running Wireshark to see the exact contents of the request that the Neo4jClient is sending.

Comment: Hi, could you please confirm what version of Neo4j you are using.

Comment: Neo4j Community 4.0.0